# QThread Char array destroyed after passing between two threads

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, qt

I have implemented a class in Qt to receive char inputs and filter them and return meaningful char arrays to me, and also this is done in a different thread than the original thread.

Here's the header file:

```
class WorkerThread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread highspeedthread;
    int bufferCounter=0;
public:
    char buffer[260];
    WorkerThread();
public slots:
    void doWork(char parameter);   // This is the function to do the filtering
signals:
    void resultReady(char*);    // Signal for when the result is made, It gets connected to HighspeedProcessor::handleresult
};

class HighspeedProcessor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread highspeedthread;
public:
    HighspeedProcessor();
signals:
    void process(char);  // This is the function from which the cycle starts
public slots:
    void handleResult(char*);  // This gets the results back
};
```

And here's the definitions:

```
void WorkerThread::doWork(char parameter)
{
    buffer[bufferCounter] = parameter;

    // Filters the input and fills the buffer
    // Code omitted for easement
    // ...

    qDebug()<<"Before: "<<buffer;
    emit resultReady(buffer);  // Pass the buffer to HighspeedProcessor::handleResult
}
HighspeedProcessor::HighspeedProcessor() {
    WorkerThread *worker = new WorkerThread;
    worker->moveToThread(&highspeedthread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(process(char)), worker, SLOT(doWork(char)));
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(resultReady(char*)), this,SLOT(handleResult(char*)));
    highspeedthread.start();
}

void HighspeedProcessor::handleResult(char *parameter)
{
    qDebug()<<"After: "<<parameter;
}
```

The WorkerThread is doing its work just fine and filters results flawlessly, but problem is that when the result is passed to the HighspeedProcessor class, the char array gets mixed up. The result is as shown below:

```
Before:  $CMDgFlushing FIFO
After:   $CMDgFlushing FIFO�:�"��ά!���j�D��@�/�]%�i�����Rր�������y�r��<�F��!]�uh����q�=S�ߠ�"�M�d
Before:  $CMDgFlushing FIFO
After:   $CMDgFlushing FIFO
Before:  $CMDgFlushing FIFO
After:   $CMDgFlushing ��o���kj���q�9   ����^ou����
```

And by the way this is not happening so frequently, meaning only once out of almost 100 times it gets mixed up and other times it's ok. Also the rate of input data is almost 1Mb/s. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: This was already happening before I used qDebug in my code. So, it's not the result of using qDebug.

Comment: Use `QByteArray` *and pass it around as value, not as pointer*. Don't use `char[]` and `char*` for multi-threaded stuff in Qt (unless you have a specific reason to do so, and can clearly state the reason). Let Qt do the work for you.

Comment: @hyde I don't have a specific reason, but there are 15-20 other functions in my code which are using char* and char[] without any problem. so I thought there's no need to change that. But I'll try your suggestion. thanks.

Comment: When ever you emit a raw pointer in Qt with queued connection, you then have two copies which point to same object. You need to somehow make sure you don't destroy the pointed-to data before nobody is going to use it any more, *and* if you have multiple threads, then you need to use mutex to protect the data, if it is going to be modified. Generally it's just so much easier to pass around some Qt copy-on-write object like QByteArray in this case.

Comment: @hyde changing all my char*'s to QByteArray solved my problem. thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes:

- Your are using the buffer in two different threads, but are passing
  only a pointer to it, it is pointless.
- Don't protect a reading/writing to the buffer
- You don't need even to use any thread-safe exchange buffer, you simply can  pass a QByteArray as a parameter between threads through signals-slots.

For example:

```
QByteArray buffer;

//...
signals:
    void resultReady(QByteArray); 
//...

void WorkerThread::doWork(char parameter)
{        
    buffer[bufferCounter] = parameter;
    //...
    emit resultReady(buffer);
}

void HighspeedProcessor::handleResult(QByteArray parameter)
{
    qDebug() << "After: "<< parameter;
}
```

Comment: it was already being destroyed before I used qDebug. I used it just to show that I am printing the result from a specific point of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my char* variables to QByteArray solved my problem. Somehow there was some conflict happening between the two threads that used the same pointer for buffer.